# Two instances of installer (Created using Inno) is shown in task manager

Tags: inno-setup

I created an installer using Inno. I had a requirement to launch installation only in admin mode. I have set the options in Inno ([Setup]: PrivilegesRequired=admin). But this is not helping me completely.
In windows 7, UAC is on. When user clicks on the installer, UAC window comes up asking for authorization. If user selects yes, two instance of the installer is seen running in task manager.
But if user right click on the installer and selects ‘run as administrator’, UAC window comes up, but this time only one instances of installer is seen in task manager. 
I have coded to run only one instance of installer to run at a time. So in the first case, installation fails. User has to always select ‘run as administrator’ to install.
Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: That is perfectly normal behaviour for Inno. One instance runs unelevated, which then runs the other through UAC. Furthermore, right click, "run as admin" actually has a detrimental effect on Inno. None of the ...AsOriginalUser functionality will work. Nothing you have explained should cause the setup to fail.

Comment: @Deanna, maybe OP is killing the spawn process and the installation fails due to that (if the *I have coded to run only one instance of installer* means some process killer). Otherwise you're definitely right!

Comment: Note that the correct way to have only one instance of the installer running is to use `CreateMutex` and `CheckForMutex` in `InitializeSetup`.  This won't be affected by the two processes (which as Deanna said is perfectly normal and desirable).

Answer (score 1):

What you see in task manager as a second process of your setup application is a spawn process that is used to run another processes with the same elevation from within your setup.

I haven't checked this deeper in InnoSetup source, but I don't think there's a way to prevent its creation. That spawn process is hidden from user's point of view and it's not something you should be afraid, just don't try to kill it manually, let it live its own live!

Anyway, you don't need to set the [`PrivilegesRequired`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_privilegesrequired.htm) directive to `admin` in your script. This is a default value of this directive, so you can remove that line.

Comment: I have a requirement where I should not allow more than one installation to continue at a time. So I am detecting the number of installation process running. If it is more than one, it throws the message to user and exits the installation. Here in this case it exits the installation. User is forced to use run as administrator mode. If I am allowing running more than installation then everything is fine. There are no issues with installation. But my requirement is to run only one installation at a time.

Comment: Then [`follow the way`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758616/two-instances-of-installer-created-using-inno-is-shown-in-task-manager#comment17251416_12758616) @Miral suggested. You're reinventing the wheel right now.